# How can I repeat the sentence on the basis of integer input?

Tags: python, string, loops

Sheldon Cooper once was knocking on the door of Penny. As we all know, he goes like “Knock! Knock! Knock! Penny! Knock! Knock! Knock! Penny! …”. He continues to knock on the door until Penny opens. It requires one second for each word. If Penny opens the door after N(input) sec, then write a
python program to print out the whole sentence generated by that time.
Note: There will only be a single input N in your program.
for this problem my code is:

```
str = "knock!knock!knock!penny"
#split string
splits = str.split()

#for loop to iterate over words array
for split in splits:
  print(split)
```

I can access each word from this sentence or I can just write the half sentence. But I can not make it iterate through the sentence.
My output should be:
input: 6
output: knock!knock!knock!penny!knock!knock!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `itertools.cycle` like this -

```
import itertools

str = "knock!knock!knock!penny"
splits = str.split('!')

n = 6
gen =  itertools.cycle(splits)
print("!".join(next(gen) for _ in range(n)))
```

In your code, you are trying to `split()` it without providing the separator (in your case `!`).

After split, you can feed your list to `itertools.cycle`. This will iterate one by one in the list and after all elements are iterated, it will go back to the first element and do this endlessly.

The for loop in `join()` will generate only that many words in the output and every two word will be joined by `!` in between.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple to achieve if you use sleep and some loop like this,

```
import time
input_string = "knock!knock!knock!penny"
splitted = input_string.split('!')

def show_knock():
    knocking = int(input("Enter Time in second : "))
    count = 0
    otp_list = []
    for i in range(knocking):
        tmp = f"{splitted[count]}!"
        otp_list.append(tmp)
        if count == 3:
            count =0
        else:
            count+=1
        time.sleep(1)
    print(''.join(otp_list))  # '!'.join(otp_list) can be used here instead of f String
```

output is `knock!knock!knock!penny!knock!knock!` for input 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
import time
str2 = "knock!knock!knock!penny"
#split string
splits = str2.split('!')

#for loop to iterate over words array
j=int(input('Enter number: '))
newl=[]
x=0
for split in range(j):
    if x==3:
        
        newl.append(splits[x])
        x=0
    else:
        
        newl.append(splits[x])
        x+=1
     time.sleep(1)
print('!'.join(newl))
```

Comment: Welcome, please accept my answer if it solves the problem @MalihaKabir